# Create class intention missing for scratch files

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I switched from Eclipse to IntelliJ since yesterday. I found an equivalent between the IDEs for everything but a basic thing : an intention to create a class that doesn't exist in the classpath in the scope of a **scratch file**.
IntelliJ only proposes the "create type parameter" intention :

[image]

While it works very well for no scratch files.

The IntelliJ IDEA used version is  2018.2.5 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-182.4892.20, built on October 16, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b19 amd64.

Comment: I expect a "create class" option from the intention proposal.

Comment: You have to configure that option in Settings in language Injections

Comment: I tested it in the case of a scratch file. I updated my question.

Comment: To see if the option is disabled you can go to ``Help -> Find Action``. (Ctrl + Alt + Insert is to create the class in the directory)

Comment: @davidxxx what do you mean by 'scratch file'?

Comment: It is an IntelliJ feature : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/scratches.html

Comment: For scratch file: Ctrl + Alt + Shift + Insert

Comment: @zlakad Thanks for that. I know all these shortcuts.In fact I would know if we can create new classes  from a java source code scratch files  but it seems not possible.

Comment: I think that I over estimated the scratch files concepts. I am not sure that my question still makes sense.

Comment: Why don't you try to change the default key map (File -> Settings) to Eclipse and see what happens?

Comment: I didn't use scratch files, the observations I made were "true" java classes, already existing in my project. When I create a new scratch file: same issue as you have. I guess you should turn to the IntelliJ forums then.

Answer (score 1):

Simple: move your mouse under Foo, and press OPTION+ENTER to invoke [intention-actions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/intention-actions.html) (that is for Mac, ALT-ENTER for windows). That feature is also called "quick fixes".

That suggests the possible ways to fix that problem. In other words: don't click on the red icon, but use

[image: fixes]

Edit: this rather looks like a bug: I just added a "Fooba bla" field to one of my existing java classes (so not in a public static void main) and I see the exact same: the OPTION+ENTER **only** shows me `Create type parameter ...`.

Edit 2: just upgraded to IntelliJ 2018.2.6, and now ... it works again. At least for me, this looks like a bug, that was introduced and quickly fixed.

Comment: No problem. I know your value and so cannot have any doubt about you :)  See you :)

Answer (score 1):

You have something wrong in your configuration or the place you are trying to create it in.

I get this when I just press Alt + Enter (on Windows, default key mapping)

[image]